# $A+B=AB$ does it follows that $AB=BA$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $A$, $B$ are two normal operators such that: $A+B=AB$ does it follow that $AB=BA$?

Comment: does it work for symmetric matrices?

Answer (score 6):

First, note that if $C$ is a normal operator which has a left inverse $D$ (so $DC=I$), then $C$ is invertible (and thus $D$ is its inverse and $CD=I$ as well).  This follows from the spectral theorem: you can identify your Hilbert space with $L^2(X)$ for some semifinite measure space $X$ and $C$ with multiplication by $f$ for some $f\in L^\infty(X)$.  If $0$ is in the essential range of $f$, then this means that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $g\in L^2(X)$ such that $\|fg\|<\epsilon\|g\|$ (choose $g$ to be supported on the set where $|f|<\epsilon$).  Since $DC=I$, we must have $D(fg)=g$ so $\|D\|\geq\|g\|/\|fg\|>1/\epsilon$.  Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, this is a contradiction.  Thus $0$ is not in the essential range of $f$, so $1/f\in L^\infty(X)$, and multiplication by $1/f$ is an inverse for $C$.

(Probably there is a more elementary argument that avoids spectral theory, but this is all I can come up with at the moment.)

Now note that $A+B=AB$ implies $(I-A)(I-B)=I-A-B+AB=I$.  Since $I-B$ is normal, by the result above this implies $(I-B)(I-A)=I$ as well.  That is, $I-A-B+BA=I$, or $BA=A+B=AB$.

Comment: If $DC=I$ then $D$ is surjective, and $C^*D^*=I$ so $D^*$ is injective. If $D$ is normal this implies $D$ is injective (because $\|Dx\|=\|D^*x\|$ for all $x$).   Then $D$ is surjective and injective so it is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

**In the finite dimensional case:**

We have $(A-I)$ invertible because
$$(A-I)(B-I)=AB-B-A+I=AB-(A+B)+I=I.$$
**Note that this doesn't show invertibility if our vector space is infinite dimensional.** To convince yourself with matrices, take the determinant of the above expression.

Now since $(A-I)B=A$,
$$A(A-I)B=A^2=(A-I)BA.$$
Because $A(A-I)=(A-I)A$, this means 
$$(A-I)AB=(A-I)BA.$$
Invertibility was shown so we cancel to obtain the result.

Comment: It is nontrivial that $(A-I)(B-I)=I$ implies $A-I$ is invertible--you must use the normality of $A$.

Comment: I don't follow. Take determinants and you get $\det(A-I)\det(B-I)=1$, and hence $\det(A-I) \neq 0$.

Comment: Given the phrasing and tags on the question, it seems clear it is asking about operators on a possibly infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: Good point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the equation to
\begin{eqnarray*}
(A-1)B=A
\end{eqnarray*}
Now assume (A-1) is non singular 
\begin{eqnarray*}
B=(A-1)^{-1}A
\end{eqnarray*}
Geometrically expand $(A-1)^{-1}$ ... so B can be expressed as a sum of powers of A , A will commute with each of these terms, so A commutes with B.

Comment: An argument like this can be made to work, but you can't necessarily expand $(A-1)^{-1}$ as a geometric series (the series need not converge).

Comment: Instead of expanding in a power-series we can compute the commutator  $[B,A]$ by using that $A = (A - 1) + 1$.

Comment: For the finite dimensional case it's true, for the infinite dimensional case i proved this result when A and B are self adjoint or invertible, now i wonder if i have this result when A and B are normal (bounded or not), or one of them is normal and the other is self adjoint or unitary or compact.

Answer (score 0):

There is a flaw in my first line equation.

**First** we will solve this problem: Let $X$ and $Y$ be normal and let $XY=I$. We will show $XY=YX$.

We have by normality 
$$||X^*Yz||=||XYz||= ||Iy|| = ||I^*y||=||(XY)^*y||= ||Y^*X^*z||=||YX^*z||.$$
It follows that $X^*Y$ is normal since normal operators are precisely those that have $||Tx||=||T^*x||$ for all $x$.
This means 
$$(X^*Y)Y^*X=Y^*X(X^*Y),$$
and by swapping the middle terms on each side
$$X^*Y^*YX=Y^*X^*XY.$$
Thus, $||(YX-XY)z||=0$ for all $z$ so $XY=YX$.

**Next** we realize that $(A-I)(B-I)=(B-I)(A-I)$ implies that $AB=BA$ by expanding and canceling and that $X=(A-I)$ and $Y=(B-I)$ are normal operators with $XY=I$. (Expand and cancel to verify this.)

Comment: Normal operators are those that commute with their adjoint, not those that preserve the norm.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are equivalent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator

Comment: I misspoke, they preserve the norm in that $||Ax||=||A^*x||$. Sorry.