# Let A and B be n × n matrices satisfying A + B = AB. Show that AB = BA.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here's my attempt:

> We have $$A=AB-B,\quad B=AB-A,$$ so $$A=(A-I)B,\quad B=A(B-I)$$
>   Combining the two yields $$A=(A-I)A(B-I)$$

To me this looks like A is similar to A, but I'm not sure if it's okay for me to conclude that $(A-I)=(B-I)^{-1}$

If this justified, we have that:

> $$(A-I)(B-I)=I\implies AB-B-A+I=I$$ but also $$(B-I)(A-I)=I=BA-B-A+I$$
>   hence $AB=BA$.

Is my assumption about the similarity of A correct? if not, why? and how can I properly solve this problem?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120098/ab-ab-does-it-follows-that-ab-ba/2120136#2120136

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that matrix multiplication is distributive:

$$(A-I)(B-I)=A(B-I)-I(B-I)=AB-A-B-(-I)=AB-(A+B)+I=I,$$

since $AB-(A+B)=\bf0$.